# Sharing the Users table between an IdentityDbContext, and a main application DbContext

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

My application (built in MVC5/EF6) needs to use a single database with two schemas:

- **identity**: To store all the AspNet identity tables for users and roles.
- **application**: To store all my general application tables.

I want to use a separate DbContext for each schema, with the `identity` one being created with the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` helper class, and the main `application` one being created in code with code first. The reason for having two DbContexts like this is so I can put the main application context in a separate assembly and use it in other related projects without having to reference Asp.Net.

However, I want to reference a table in the `application` schema/context with a foreign key that I want to add to the `identity.AspNetUsers` table, along with some other extra fields. I then want to create a `Users` entity in the main context that maps to the `identity.AspNetUsers` table.

For example, I want an `application.Tenants` table of which `identity.AspNetUsers` has a foreign key to, so that I can have many users belonging to a single tenant.

All this is fine I think and will work with no problems, except when it comes to creating the database, and possibly any migrations that affect that table, as I'll have two DbContext's trying to create the same table.

Can I mark a table within `OnModelCreating` as "do not create", and if so how do I add the foreign key constraint? If not then how do I handle this? I don't think what I'm trying to do is unreasonable. I just want to avoid having two "Users" tables linked with an implied foreign key (i.e. with no actual foreign key constraint).

Answer (score 2):

Why exactly do you want to use two separate `DbContext`s? It would be easier to have a single context for both ASP.NET identity data and your business entities:

```
public class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext<UserInfo>
{
    public virtual DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; } // Your business entities

    public DatabaseContext()
        : base("name=DatabaseContext")
    {
    }
}
```

Notice that the `DatabaseContext` inherits from the `IdentityDbContext<UserInfo>`.

There are some trade-offs with this approach: for example, your data access layer should reference `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core` and `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`; however, having a single database context in your project makes things much easier if you are using dependency injection or Entity Framework migrations.

Comment: I don't want to use a single DbContext, because I want the application stuff in a separate assembly so I can use it in other projects that reference the same database, but I don't want that to include anything specific to Asp.Net. I'll edit my question and make that clear...

Comment: I need to do exactly the same thing now. In Postgres, I have split the different DB Contexts over schemas, allowing me to have all the "core" tables in 'public' and business logic tables in another schema.

I just want to add the IDentityUser as a column, but it seems harder than I expected.